# Laravel Backpack - Customize Export filename

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-backpack, laravel-backpack-5

I have installed laravel backpack on my local. I am trying to modify the filename of exported file with this format *TableName _YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS*. But can't find the option to do that in backpack.

Here's what I add for adding the export button in my table Controller.

```
$this->crud->enableExportButtons();
```

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, the exported file is created in the client, it's a [DataTables feature](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html), that's why you can set a custom filename in the `export_buttons.blade.php` view file.

The vendor file is `vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/inc/export_buttons.blade.php`, you should probably copy that to `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/inc/export_buttons.blade.php` and edit the latter.

There is an array of buttons in the config options of `window.crud.dataTableConfiguration.buttons`. Each of the buttons has multiple properties like `name`, `extend`, `exportOptions`, `action`. Add another option `title` to the button you want to set the filename for.

`title: '{{$crud->model->getTable().'_'.now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}',` will get you something pretty close to what you want I hope.

Comment: Can confirm! The export is done by DataTables, using js (in the client). Thanks for the answer Matt!